# What permissions do I need for a user to see all entries in a list where typical users can see only their own submissions?

Tags: list, permissions, security

I have a list where users can create and see their own items, but not other users' items. I, being the site owner, can see all items. How can I give specific users within a Sharepoint Group the ability to see all the list items as well?

Comment: How do your restrictions implemented - via SPList.ReadSecurity or by defining item-level permissions?

Comment: @AlexBoev In the list's advanced settings I defined item-level permissions. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming in the list's Advanced Settings page you set "Specify which items users can read" to "Only their own".

You need at least the "Manage Lists" permission which is present in the following roles by default:

- Manage Hierarchy
- Design
- Full Control

So... a user would need at least the "Manage Hierarchy" role set in the list's permissions.

See also,  [Configure whether users can read or edit items in a list](https://web.archive.org/web/20121017090810/http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58).